# How do I use a laptop as a 802.11n router?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-router, 802.11n

My current wireless router seems to be broken and refusing wifi connections, so I connected a old laptop to it and created an ad-hoc network so that other computers can via the laptop. This works, but for some reason the network seems to be limited to 802.11g despite that the laptop and all devices connecting to it use 802.11n cards.

Is there a better way to do this so that I am not limited to g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, without the actual specifics... you know, like the make and model of your laptop so we can confirm that it actually does have an 802.11n card in it, all of this is speculation.

For example, if you are using an [Intel Centrino based product](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-025393.htm), you are limited to the B/G for an ad hoc network if you want to use the 2.4ghz band, and A if you want to use the 5ghz band.

This does not mean that an AD Hoc Network can't be set up.  For example, if you were using a Linksys Rangeplus Wireless-N USB apdater v2.0, in the hardware properties dialog you would find an option to enable ad hoc 802.11n support.  It is disabled by default.  You can check the hardware properties dialog of your network adapter to see if you also have this option, and if it is disabled by default.  Enabling it may allow you to increase connection speeds.

Of course, now you might be seeing why including more information is helpful.